# Word VBA - getting text file output to look right

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, format

I'm not a VBA programmer but have been researching how to make a certain task easier. I've been able to figure out code to do 95% of what I need but now I'm stuck and don't know the correct keywords to figure out a solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Background:
What I'm trying to do is extract all the text in the header/footer section of an Xx page document to a text file. Every page is a new section with different header/footer content. I have that part working.

```
Sub test()
'Dim oApp As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oSec As Word.Section
Dim oPageStart As Word.Range
Dim iPage As Integer, iTotalPages As Integer, iSection As Integer
Dim sHeader As String, sFooter As String, chk1 As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\path\Output_Example.txt")

'Open the document
'Set oApp = New Word.Application
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
iTotalPages = oDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)


'Retrieve the headers and footers on each page
With oDoc

    iSection = 0

    For iPage = 1 To iTotalPages

        'Go to the page represented by the page number iPage and
        'retrieve its section
        Set oPageStart = oDoc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, _
                                   Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=iPage)
        Set oSec = oPageStart.Sections(1)

        'If this is a different section than the one in the previous
        'iteration and it has a first page header/.footer, then
        'retrieve the first page header/footer for this section.
        'Otherwise, retrieve the primary header/footer for this section
        If (iSection < oSec.Index) And _
           (oSec.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter) Then
            sHeader = oSec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text
            sFooter = oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text
        Else
            sHeader = oSec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
            sFooter = oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
        End If

        iSection = oSec.Index

        oFile.WriteLine "Page " & iPage & ", Section " & iSection & ":"
        oFile.WriteLine "   Header3: " & sHeader
        oFile.WriteLine "   Footer: " & sFooter

    Next

    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End With End Sub
```

The above code works to grap the text in each header/footer section and makes a text file.

The Problem:
The problem is that the text lacks any formatting:
[Example ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCQqZ.jpg)

Is there a way to make it look more the text in the header section:
[What the word doc looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoRQV.jpg)

I don't care about the right and left justification, I just need the line breaks to show up in the text file. I assume the box looking things are special characters but i can't seem to find the right way to handle them.

Should i be using something other than `Scripting.FileSystemObject`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Plain text doesn't *have* formatting.  That's why they call it **plain** text.

Comment: Replace the box characters with a carriage return and a newline (\r\n) ?  Do you need help with how to replace the box character or finding out what Char(#) the box is?

Comment: Something like `variable.Replace chr(13),"\r\n" ` What is the difference the single box and double box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this section:

```
oFile.WriteLine "Page " & iPage & ", Section " & iSection & ":"
oFile.WriteLine "   Header3: " & sHeader
oFile.WriteLine "   Footer: " & sFooter
```

to

```
oFile.WriteLine "Page " & iPage & ", Section " & iSection & ":"
WriteHeadFootLines sHeader, oFile, "Header3"
WriteHeadFootLines sFooter, oFile, "Footer"
```

And add this sub:

```
Sub WriteHeadFootLines(sHeader As String, oFile As Object, sPrefix As String)

    Dim arrHeader() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    arrHeader() = Split(sHeader, Chr(13))

    For i = LBound(arrHeader) To UBound(arrHeader)
        If i = LBound(arrHeader) Then
            oFile.WriteLine "   " & sPrefix & ": " & arrHeader(i)
        Else
            oFile.WriteLine "            " & arrHeader(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Garth. That helped a lot. I still have squares showing up. I was trying `chk1 = Replace(sHeader, Chr(13), "XX")` and it replaces some but not others. How can i tell what the ASCII value is for the remaining squares?

Comment: I got it. They were chr(7) "Bell". Thanks again.