# Word VBA: Convert Superscripts in Footers/Headers

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, footer

I'm using code like this to output all the headers/footers per section to a text file:
[Word VBA - getting text file output to look right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772226/word-vba-getting-text-file-output-to-look-right)

I've been able to convert all the special characters in the sHeader/sFooter string variables using Replace() without a problem.

Example: `sFooter = Replace(sFooter, ChrW(8804), "^R'\ {\uc2\u8804 <=}'")`

All is great until I try to replace a superscript. Alt+x only gives me the value of the letter itself. I've tried looking up the hex value (may not even be a thing) with no success. I've even tried the different Latin character values.

I recorded a macro to see how Word would replace it and got:

```
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find.Font
    .Superscript = True
    .Subscript = False
End With

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "A"
    .Replacement.Text = "^super{a}"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

The problem is I don't know how to use them together. 
I tried to use `oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Find...` instead of `Selection.Find...` but that results in a null string.

Can I make a String object somehow from sHeader/sFooter so I can utilize the recorded macro code? I tried googling, converting string to object, but didn't get anything help. Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you M1chael for your input.

I was able to get the recorded macro above to work by setting the selection to the current header/footer section.

Example:

```
oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select
Selection = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly answering your question, but the problem is that the character is the same regardless of whether it is superscript or not, i.e. superscript is formatting, just like bold or italics.

For example, a bold A, a normal A and a superscript A all have code 65.

If you are saving to a text file, you won't be able to save formatting, so you would need to invent your own representation for a superscript character.

The representation from the Find/Replace code, i.e. "^super{a}" is what Word uses to allow you to do Find/Replace on text with a specific formatting.

Note: There are some special characters such as ² which have a separate character code to 2, so these would have a different code.